# Users are not returned from the mongo collection (Pymongo/Docker-compose)

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, pymongo

Users are not returned from the mongo collection.
This is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from celery import Celery
from loguru import logger
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configuração do Celery para utilizar o RabbitMQ como broker
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'pyamqp://admin:admin@rabbitmq:5672//'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'rpc'  # Pode usar como 'rpc' ou 'amqp'

# Inicialização do Celery
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def status():
    return 'Pong!'

@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_users():
    """Get all users from the 'users' collection in MongoDB""" 
    try:
        logger.info("Getting users from MongoDB")
        client = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/')
        db = client['test']
        collection = db['Users']
        users = collection.find()
        
        return jsonify({"users": [user for user in users]})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error getting users from MongoDB: {e}")
        return jsonify({"error": f"Error getting users from MongoDB: {e}"}), 500

@app.route('/users', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    """Create a new user in the 'users' collection in MongoDB""" 
    try:
        logger.info("Creating user in MongoDB")
        client = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/')
        db = client['users']
        collection = db['Users']
        user = {"name": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}
        logger.info(f"User to be inserted: {user}")
        result = collection.insert_one(user)
        logger.info(f"User inserted: {result}")
        return jsonify({"id": str(result)})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error creating user in MongoDB: {e}")
        return f"Error creating user in MongoDB: {e}"
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
      - nginx

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MONGO_URI="mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
      - ./mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf:ro


  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq

volumes:
  mongodb_data:
  rabbitmq_data:
```

when i post, i get back the object_id created in the collection. but get doesn't return users, just an empty array. can anyone tell me how to return the users created from the POST route I showed in the examples above?

I've tried changing the name of the collection and the like, but I still haven't managed to solve it.

Comment: You are using a different database 
for the post request  db = client['users']
for the get request  db = client['test']